# Access minikube service hosted on VM from host

Tags: kubernetes, virtualbox, minikube

I'm working on a VM virtual Box, running Ubuntu.
I have created on it a Kubernetes service, using Minikube, exposing an hello-world app.

```
NAME        TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
hello-world    NodePort   10.99.59.211    <none>        8080:32453/TCP   2h

minikube ip
192.168.49.2
```

Now, the app is reacheable inside vm through the browser at

```
http://192.168.49.2:32453
```

but if i try to open the hello world app from host browser, it is un-reacheable.

i already set up the port farwarding in virtualbox, and it works fine if, for example, i run the apache server in vm,   but not for my app. [see port forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czrh1.png)

the link

```
http://localhost:9090
```

is not reacheable from host machine so i can't reache my app running on vm.

can you help?
thank you so much.

Comment: Could you share your yaml configs? What is the actual error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

In your VirtualBox Port Forwarding Rules you did not provide an IP address for your guest IP so it uses the default 127.0.0.1 loopback IP address. so you are forwarding traffic from 127.0.0.1:9090 to 127.0.0.1:32453. so it will be unreachable since you are actually trying to reach 192.168.49.2:32453 and not 127.0.0.1:32453. So input 192.168.49.2 as the guest IP value.

if you still have an issue reaching 192.168.49.2:32453, then the most likely issue is that your host machine does not recognize the ip address 192.168.49.2 so you should not be using it in the VirtualBox Port Forwarding Rule. "ifconfig" command will confirm this as 192.168.49.2 will not be listed. So you should only be using ip addresses in this "ifconfig" list, in your VirtualBox Port Forwarding Rules. A good candidate from this list to use will be your 127.0.0.1 loopback ip address. So to resolve this, traffic from your loopback address inside your VM should be forwarded to 192.168.49.2:32453. You will go about this by installing socat

`sudo apt-get install socat`

Then for the port forwarding you can do something like this

`sudo socat TCP4-LISTEN:3012,fork TCP4:192.168.49.2:32453`

now you can finally set your VirtualBox Port Forwarding Rules to Forward to port 3012
[image]